# Accessing nested hashes using variables

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a nested hash like so:

```
someVar = { key1: { key2: 'value' } }
```

I can access the value by using it in this manner:

```
someVar[:key1][:key2]
```

How would I access it using a variable?

```
hashObj = { key1: { key2: 'value' } }
oneKey = "key1"
twoKey = "key2"

puts hashObj[:key1]            # Works
puts hashObj[:key1][:key2]     # Works

puts hashObj[oneKey]           # Blank
puts hashObj[oneKey][twoKey]   # Error
```

I'm sure there is a duplicate of this question somewhere, but I can't seem to locate one however.

Comment: @the Tin Man Any reason why you put in such a small edit?  Doesn't make the question any more or less clear.

Comment: The edit made the wording more direct, and fixed some grammatical errors. Stack Overflow aims to be like the Wikipedia of programming problems and solutions. Grammar matters, as does conciseness. People like to be friendly, as if SO is a BBS or chat, but it's not. Instead, it's a kinder and gentler encyclopedia.

Comment: @theTinMan There weren't grammatical issues though, nor was the question indirect (in my opinion).  You can edit how you feel though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your keys are symbols, and you are trying to accessing them using strings. Turn them into symbols:

```
puts hashObj[oneKey.to_sym][twoKey.to_sym]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find it convenient to write a small method to extract the values you want:

```
def get_val(h, *keys)
  keys.reduce(h) do |h,k|
    v = h[k]
    return v unless v.is_a? Hash
    v
  end
end

h = { key1: { key2: 'cat' }, key3: { key4: { key5: 'dog' } } } 

get_val(h, :key1, :key2)        #=> "cat"
get_val(h, :key3, :key4, :key5) #=> "dog"
```

Some error-checking would be needed, should, for example,

```
get_val(h, :key1, :key2, :key3)
```

is entered.

Edit: With Ruby 2.3+ you can improve this by using [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig):

```
def get_val(h, *keys)
  h.dig *keys
end

 get_val(h, :key3, :key4, :key5)
   #=> "dog" 
 get_val(h, :key3, :key4)
   #=> {:key5=>"dog"} 
 get_val(h, :key3, :key4, :key5)
   #=> "dog" 
 get_val(h, :key3, :key5, :key4)
   #=> nil
```